# How to get a scrollbar to appear and work successfully in a panel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm fairly new to asp and i am trying to understand why exactly this is not working.

What i atempting to do is set up a panel within a page that will have both horizontal and vertical scrollbars on the page.
The page is set up like this:

a header

a panel:
Inbetween that is a large amount of literal statements along with headers that have anchor tags along with return to top anchor tags, and a few images.

and then a footer.

All of this works.

However, when i open the page in a browser, the panel does not have a scroll bar appear. This causes for only the first 1000px or so of the statements inbetween the panels to appear. Also if you click one of the anchor tags at the top of the page it will lead to another section of the panel. Which is what i want it to do, however, it will only show the beginning of that section and then that somehow spills over into and covers the footer of the page.

```
<body style="background-color:#C9E8FF; overflow:hidden; width:100%; height:100%">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"  Width="100%" Height="100%"
    ScrollBars="Both" style="margin-right: 145px">
```

html/asp inbetween panel.

```
</asp:Panel>
</body>
```

What i think the problem has something to do with the way height has been declared, however even when i give heigh the exact px value i need or just do not include height i still have the same issue stated above.
this is the panel i am using.

What i would like to know is what, is the reason for why this panel is not working correctly and how to fix it.

Any help of suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to specify width on a Panel. If not width is defined, the default is 100% (just like a DIV, which is all a Panel really is). That could actually be part of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I applied the 100% width and height to both the body and the html elements as well as setting the margin to 0.

I also included some javascript to add some dummy content.

Hope it helps.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var html = ''
            for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                html += 'Some default content...<br/>';
            }
            $('#content').html(html);
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        html, body
        {
            margin:0px;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            overflow:hidden;
            background-color:#C9E8FF;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"  Width="100%" Height="100%"
    ScrollBars="Both" style="margin-right: 145px">
        <div id="content"></div>
</asp:Panel>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would enclose the panel in a regular div and set the style to the div to be overflow:scroll.

That should create scrollbars for you automatically when the panel's width exceeds the div's width. [See here a little example.](http://jsfiddle.net/6D5x6/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove overflow:hidden from CSS styling html,body.

because this hides any overflow or scroll bar on the page.

Regards,
Ajay